# What did ancient Romans wear when sleeping?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-republic, clothing

What type of clothes did ancient Roman citizens wear at bedtime? Did they wear anything at all?

I would like to focus on the late republican period, around 50-27BC.

As a bonus, I would love to make the same questions for slaves in the city of Rome.

Comment: A quick search found this which mentions clothing a bit (not sure what time period): https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1hsart/how_did_romans_prepare_for_bed_and_what_kind_of/

Comment: Indeed, English is not my native language so I might have used bad keywords when searching. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ancient Romans had no special sleepwear. They typically slept in their underclothes, which they also would have worn around the home. Here's a relevant quote from *[Everyday Life in Ancient Rome](https://books.google.com/books?id=8UoqKfh2azIC&pg=PA31)* by Lionel Casson.

> The morning toilette for the master of the house was simple and quick.
>   As was the universal ancient practice, he had slept in his
>   underclothes—a light sleeveless knee-length tunic and under it a
>   loincloth, which functioned as undershorts. It took him but a moment
>   to slip on his sandals... and if his day included a formal morning call or a session in the Senate or law courts or the like, put on his toga.